# Using Promise from Reactjs-promise returns an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

I'm trying to use reactjs-promise to get a value from an Ajax request, assign it to the component state, and use it in render() as follow:

```
import Promise from 'react-promise';
.....


componentWillMount(){
    var prom = new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        console.log("test1")    // Line A
        resolve(this.getUserID())
    });
    prom.then( value => {
        this.setState({userID: value})
    } )
},

getUserID(){
    console.log("test2")      //Line B
    var userID = null;
    // Call another method to run the ajax request...
    // ....
    return userID
},

render() {
    console.log(this.state.userID)
    return (....)
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: prom.then is not a function
```

Basically, I tried to follow the example here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-promise . Also, I expected `Line A` and `Line B` to show up in the console, but none of them happens. Can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: First things first, you're just using standard Promises here and not Reactjs-promise.   Reactjs-promise uses a `promise` and `then` tag on a React DOM Node to set the content of a variable

Comment: @Alex ok.... so shouldn't that set the variable's content now?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are overriding the default reserved variable `Promise` with the `react-promise` library, instead you should change your import statement to:

```
import Async from 'react-promise';
```

Then you will be able to create a Promise object and pass that Promise as props to a node to be rendered by React (as described in the docs).  For example:

```
import Async from 'react-promise'

let prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(function () {
     resolve('a value')
   }, 100)
})

const ExampleWithAsync = (props) => <Async promise={prom} then={(val) => <div>{val}</div>/>
```

The above code will set "a value" inside of the div upon resolving.

Comment: Thanks! So basically the problem was the import part! Now I'm not getting the error anymore, and the test lines are also printed on the console. But the  `userID` state is not set yet. So if the promise was resolved it should set the state, right? I mean ` prom.then( value => { this.setState({userID: value})    } )` should make sure that there is a value to be assigned to `userID`. But why it doesn't work?

Comment: so this is just a guess (because your full implementation of `getUserID` is commented out).  But currently you set `userID = null;` then fire an AJAX request  but you immediately `return userID` meaning that the callback from the request won't be the result returned as `return userID` is invoked immediately, resulting in your userID in state to be set to null.   You could test this by setting `userID = 0` before your AJAX request, then your state should reflect with `userID : 0`

Comment: I mean, I don't need the `Async` component. I need to set some states.... maybe I should better to use this (I guess it's the standard promise you were talking about): https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise

Comment: You could use that yes, if you're writing client code then an implementation of `Promise` is shipped with modern browsers, but if you're wanting to support older clients then installing that module is probably a good idea.

Comment: You are right, the `return userID` is returning the initial value of it which is null

Comment: You can solve this either by providing a callback parameter in the `getUserID` function, or you can just make the `getUserID` function return a promise and then set the state on `getUserId().then(...)`